# Jsoup throws an exception when it doesn't find the html element

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm making a crawler with java using jsoup, the problem is that the site i'm crawling not all pages have an address that could be shown up in google maps, my program fails when i try to get the latitude and longitude from google  maps and the page doesn't have this element aviable.

I make a simple check if there is the html element

```
   if( !doc.getElementsByTag("noscript").first().select("img").attr("src").isEmpty()){
```

that's where it fails, although is supposed to check if the element is empty to avoid print on the console the info it throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ewisemapsTest.MetrosCubicosCrawler.crawlLiga(Unknown Source)
    at ewisemapsTest.MetrosCubicosCrawler.crawl(Unknown Source)
    at ewisemapsTest.MetrosCubicosCrawler.main(Unknown Source)
```

the java code where it fails:

```
  if( !doc.getElementsByTag("noscript").first().select("img").attr("src").isEmpty()){

                          String latLon = doc.getElementsByTag("noscript").first().select("img").attr("src");


                            int inicio = latLon.indexOf("=")+1;
                            int medio = latLon.indexOf("%");
                            int fin = latLon.indexOf("&");

                            String lat = latLon.substring(inicio, medio);
                            String lon = latLon.substring((medio+3), fin);
                            System.out.println("\nCoordenadas lat:"+lat +" lon: " + lon); 
                          }
```

what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first()` returns `null` if the set is empty. You need to verify that it isn't before continuing.

```
Element element = doc.getElementsByTag("noscript").first();
if (element != null && !element.select("img").attr("src").isEmpty())
{
}
```

Note you should double check the other methods you are calling and ensure you are handling their "failure" cases correctly. Some will likely transform an empty list to an empty list but others might not.

Comment: This one's apparently better solution!